# Canonical reference for Naive Bayes classifier

Tags: bayesian, naive-bayes, references

I'm looking for a reference for the Naive bayse classifier to put in my work. Not sure what I'm missing but a [scholar search](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=Naive%20Bayes%20classifier&btnG=Search&as_sdt=0,5&as_ylo=&as_yhi=&as_vis=1)  didn't yield any meaningful results. any idea ?

**update**: I meant for a reference to put in the bibliography...

Comment: If you look at [Bayes classifier](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Bayes+classifier) on this forum, you will find a considerable number of entries.

Comment: @Xi'an. thanks. I know what NB is. I just  looking for for a reference to put in the bibliography...

Comment: That’s a terrible way to write a bibliography.

I suggest *An Essay towards solving a Problem in the Doctrine of Chances*, Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society of London, Thomas Bayes, 1763. But **read it**.

Comment: @Elvis. thanks - but why this is so terrible  ? :)

Comment: I really don’t like when some references are always quoted but no one never take the time to read them. I think you should quote your favorite textbook about classification, instead of a "princeps paper" that you don’t really care about.

Comment: @Elvis my advisor told me, that one should reference always the original paper of an algorithm ... how does the tradeoff graph for read-it and first-reference looks like ;) ? Anways, should make an anwser !

Comment: @steffen In some cases, your advisor is right: for example, when dealing with an EM algorithm, you always refer to Dempster, Laird and Rubin (1977). However in my opinion this means that people dealing with EM should take the time to at least have a look on this paper... But I appreciate when people, besides Dempster et al, have the honesty to refer to one of the textbooks they actually prefer. .../...

Comment: If your paper is very technical and unlikely to be read by someone who doesn’t master EM, refering to Dempster is merely proving that you know the rules and codes of the community. But if your paper is an application to EM to a particular problem, in e.g. genetics or ecology, refering to Dempster is of no practical use. Some of our readers won’t know this algorithm, and what they need to read is not the princeps paper (that you refered without reading it!) but a good and pedagogical introduction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the comments to the question (by @Elvis)..."t An Essay towards solving a Problem in the Doctrine of Chances, Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society of London, Thomas Bayes, 1763"

Comment: I don't think this is an appropriate reference; my understanding is that the Naive Bayes classifier is something different than Bayes law.